# Remove elements in a list using a pattern

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Greeting everyone. I'm trying to write an algorithm in Racket but I'm faced with a problem:

I'm studying way of generating different types of grids over surfaces, using a CAD software as a backend for Racket. Basically I have a function that generates a matrix of point coordinates (in the u and v domains) of a parametric surface and another one which connects those points with a line, in a certain order, to create the grid pattern. The problem is, to obtain more complex grids I need to be able to remove certain points from that matrix.

With that said, I have a list of data (points in my case) and I want to remove items from that list based on a **true-false-false-true** pattern. For example, given the list '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) the algorithm would keep the first element, remove the next two, keep the third and then iterate the same patter for the rest of the list, returning as the final result the list '(0 3 4 7 8).

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Racket's `for` loops:

```
(define (pattern-filter pat lst)
  (reverse
   (for/fold ((res null)) ((p (in-cycle pat)) (e (in-list lst)))
     (if p (cons e res) res))))
```

testing

```
> (pattern-filter '(#t #f #f #t)  '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
'(0 3 4 7 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using list functions in SRFI-1:

```
#!racket
(require srfi/1)
(define (pattern-filter pat lst)
  (fold-right (λ (p e acc) (if p (cons e acc) acc))
              '()
              (apply circular-list pat)
              lst))

(pattern-filter '(#t #f #f #t)  
                '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) ; ==> '(0 3 4 7 8)
```

There are other ways but it won't become easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

In Racket I would probably use `match` to express the specific pattern you described:

```
#lang racket

(define (f xs)
  (match xs
    [(list* a _ _ d more) (list* a d (f more))]
    [(cons a _)           (list a)]
    [_                    (list)]))

(require rackunit)
;; Your example:
(check-equal? (f '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) '(0 3 4 7 8))
;; Other tests:
(check-equal? (f '())           '())
(check-equal? (f '(0))          '(0))
(check-equal? (f '(0 1))        '(0))
(check-equal? (f '(0 1 2))      '(0))
(check-equal? (f '(0 1 2 3))    '(0 3))
(check-equal? (f '(0 1 2 3 4))  '(0 3 4))
```

However I also like (and upvoted) both usepla's and Sylwester's answers because they generalize the pattern.

---

**Update**: My original example used `(list a _ _ d more ...)` and `(list a _ ...)` match patterns. [But that's slow!](http://www.greghendershott.com/2014/06/destructuring-lists-with-match.html) Instead use `(list* a _ _ d more)` and `(cons a _)`, respectively. That expands to the sort of fast code you'd write manually with `cond` and list primitives.

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged with both [scheme](/questions/tagged/scheme) and [racket](/questions/tagged/racket), so it's probably not a bad idea to have an implementation that works in Scheme in addition to the versions that work for Racket given in some of the other answers.  This uses the same type of approach that's seen in some of those other answers:  create an infinite repetition of your boolean pattern and iterate down it and the input list, keeping the elements where your pattern is true.

Here's a method that takes a list of elements and a list of #t and #f, and returns a list of the elements that were at the same position as #t in the pattern.  It ends whenever elements or pattern has no more elements.

```
(define (keep elements pattern)
  ;; Simple implementation, non-tail recursive
  (if (or (null? elements)
          (null? pattern))
      '()
      (let ((tail (keep (cdr elements) (cdr pattern))))
        (if (car pattern)
            (cons (car elements) tail)
            tail))))

(define (keep elements pattern)
  ;; Tail recursive version with accumulator and final reverse
  (let keep ((elements elements)
             (pattern pattern)
             (result '()))
    (if (or (null? elements)
            (null? pattern))
        (reverse result)
        (keep (cdr elements)
              (cdr pattern)
              (if (car pattern)
                  (cons (car elements) result)
                  result)))))
```

To get an appropriate repeating pattern, we can create a circular list of the form (#t #f #f #t …) we can create a list (#t #f #f #t) and then destructively concatenate it with itself using nconc.  (I called it nconc because I've got a Common Lisp background.  In Scheme, it's probably more idiomatic to call it append!.)

```
(define (nconc x y)
  (if (null? x) y
      (let advance ((tail x))
        (cond
         ((null? (cdr tail))
          (set-cdr! tail y)
          x)
         (else 
          (advance (cdr tail)))))))
```

```
(let ((a (list 1 2 3)))
  (nconc a a))
;=> #0=(1 2 3 . #0#)
```

Thus, we have a solution:

```
(let ((patt (list #t #f #f #t)))
  (keep '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) (nconc patt patt)))
;=> (0 3 4 7 8)
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  It works in plain [tag:scheme] since the question is tagged with [tag:scheme].  I'm not sure that any of the other answers do that…